# Opendaylight: Getting notification on flow miss event

Tags: opendaylight

I want to build an Opendaylight Boron application which needs to field notifications from MDSAL when a flow miss event is encountered and the packet is sent up to the controller for processing. How can I solicit such events?

If it were possible to register for ALL openflow notifications, that would suffice.

Any pointers or code snippets to do this?

Thank you,

Ranga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packets that are sent from the switch to the controller are called PacketIn packets.

You need to create a Java class that *listens* for PacketIn by implementing the OpenDaylight PacketProcessingListener interface.

Here's an [example tutorial](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:MD-SAL_App_Tutorial#Processing_a_PacketInNotification).

And here is an [example of a class I wrote in the SFC project](https://github.com/opendaylight/sfc/blob/master/sfc-renderers/sfc-openflow-renderer/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/sfc/ofrenderer/openflow/SfcIpv4PacketInHandler.java) that handles PacketIn packets sent to the controller from OVS:

Answer (score 0):

Add a flow such that the default action is punt to controller and all the other flsow with higher priority, such that missed matches will be forwarded to controller.

```
cookie=0x3900000, duration=1s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=10 in_port=1 actions=output:2
cookie=0x2900000, duration=1s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535
```

Comment: This answer explains how to create a flow to send a PacketIn to the controller, but the question is how to handle these packets in the OpenDaylight controller.